# Hi, I am trying to implement Stripe Checkout for Credit Card validation and Payments

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe Checkout for Credit Card validation and Payments. Since we are not PCI complaint, what can be the best option or method to implement this?

Stripe Checkout and Stripe Elements, where to start on this and Quickstart guide.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use Stripe Checkout or Stripe Elements, you don't need to worry about PCI-compliance. This way, the credit card information never touches your application and is sent directly to Stripe.

You can choose [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout) if you don't want to build a checkout page yourself. Alternatively, [Stripe Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) provides a secure and PCI-compliant checkout form, that you can use on your own checkout page.